# Zend_Mail_Transport_Smtp for Zoho mail

Tags: zend-framework, smtp, sendmail

I have been trying to use Zoho mail to send emails.  I have found a lot of examples on how to do this with Gmail, but not Zoho.  Gmail works fine with this same code (different port and server, or course)

```
$mailConfig = array(
    'ssl' => 'tls',
    'port' => '465',
    'auth' => 'login',
    'username' => [username],
    'password' => [password]);

    $transport = new Zend_Mail_Transport_Smtp('smtp.zoho.com', $mailConfig);

    Zend_Mail::setDefaultTransport($transport);
```

When I try to send an email, I get an error:

> 'Zend_Mail_Protocol_Exception' with message 'Could not read from smtp.zoho.com' in /Applications/MAMP/zend/zend1.11/library/Zend/Mail/Protocol/Abstract.php:385

Does anyone know how to connect to Zoho SMTP?

Answer (score 2):

I had the exact same issue. What worked for me was doing the following. TLS works for Gmail, however for Zoho, you need to use "SSL" as the SSL option so that port number 465 is used.

This is how I have mine setup:

```
$mailConfig => array(
    'name'              => '<domain>',
    'host'              => 'smtp.zoho.com',
    'port'              => 465,
    'connection_class'  => 'login',
    'connection_config' => array(
            'username' => '<user@domain>',
            'password' => '<my_password>',
            'ssl'      => 'ssl',
    ),
),
```

Just change `<domain>`, `<user@domain>`, and `<my_password>` and this should do the trick!